# Android video recorded with MediaRecorder is disorted/ scaled to the sides

Tags: android, video, camera, android-mediarecorder

I write this code to record a Video with the MediaRecorder in the Background without preview

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
camera = Camera.open();
camera.unlock();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));       
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Videos/");
if(!file.exists())
    file.mkdirs();
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + "/Videos/Video " + DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime()) + ".mp4");
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
try {
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the SurfaceView init:

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) self.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
surfaceView = new SurfaceView(self.getApplicationContext());
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    1, 1,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

The Video i recorded looks disorted like scaled too much to the sides.
The holder is the SurfaceHolder given in the surfaceCreated method.

[this is a screenshot of an example video. note: the square should be quadrangular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhGYd.jpg)

Comment: Could you upload an example frame?

Comment: ive added a screenshot

Comment: Have you tried to play this movie on a PC?

Comment: jep it looks also like this. and with different mobile players too

Comment: Which device is that?

Comment: tested on galaxy s4 and galaxy s3. same problem